# Can't add params to Angular route

Tags: angular, inheritance, lazy-loading, angular-router

I am trying to use Angular Routing for a simple master-detail interface and I just can't manage to get my routing working whenever there are parameters in it.

I have this Master component

```
    export class PersonMasterComponent extends MasterExtentionService implements OnInit {
       constructor(
           private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
           private _router: Router,
           private contService: ContactService) 
            { super(contService, _snackBar, null, _router) }
}
```

Which inherits from:

```
        Injectable()
        export class MasterExtentionService {

        constructor(private dataService: DataService,
                private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
                private matDialog?: MatDialog
                , private router?: Router
            ) { }
        ...
            edit(id: number) {
        ...
                    this.router.navigate(['crm', 'contacts','detail', id]); // I just type the URL directly for 
                                                                            // this example, this 
                                                                            // will be a variable.
                                                                            // i've trie navigateByUrl as 
                                                                            //  well
                }
            }
}
```

`edit()` gets called whenever a row gets clicked on the master component.

I've done this a thousand times before, but I just can't seem to find whats wrong here. (I had been stuck in Angular 7, just switched to 9)

Here are my app routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crm', loadChildren: () => import('./crm/crm.module').then(m => m.CrmModule), canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
}
```

Here are my CRM module routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'contacts/detail/:id', component: PersonDetailComponent }, // I am trying to call this guy 
                                                                     // from PersonMasterComponent

  { path: 'contacts', component: PersonMasterComponent, children: [
    // { path: 'detail/:id', component: PersonDetailComponent,  }, // tried doing this didn't work
  ] },

  { path: 'businesses/:id', component: PersonMasterComponent },
  { path: '', component: CrmComponent }

];
```

Whenever I try to navigate the router does recognize the route as existing, but it just quickly comes back to the initial route and reloads the master component.

The problem only seems to happen whenever there are parameters on my route.  I have a feeling that I am missing something very basic.

I came across this problem yesterday and it's driving me nuts.  Any help will be deeply appreciated.

--EDIT
Here are the logs the router gives when subscribing to router.events
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rpQRIQJ6UifEsAzIRaWIFbnly4ttljLrOxejuExXVbs/edit

It does seem like the correct route is found, but just immediately goes back.
This only seems to happen when I try to load the component from a component that is in the same lazy loaded module, I was able to load it from other parts of the app.

Cheers.

Comment: what's the url that you type in the adress bar ? and to what url does it redirect you ? please provide all the necessary info so that we can tell you whats wrong

Comment: can you please provide stackblitz url ? I can fix it there.. it will helpful to understand issue.

Comment: @RachidO 
Whenever I'm on 
/crm/contacts
And I wan't to move to 
/crm/contacts/detail/:id

is when the probelm arises.

Comment: @piyushjain
I tried replicating the issue in stackblitz, but it did get it to work there.  
I am analysing the differences between the two projects.

Answer (score 0):

the verify first item in the navigate should start with the leading `/`, otherwise it doesn't respect the root.

```js
this.router.navigate(['/crm', 'contacts','detail', id]); // <- /crm
```

Comment: Might you verify that id isn't empty?

Comment: Yup, it's not empty.  If I leave it empty I get the usual: 
Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'crm/businesses'

Whenever Id isn't empty I actually see the url change for a fraction of a second, but it immediately goes back to the initial URL.There is nothing logged on the console and NgOnInit is never run on the target component.

Comment: Aha, that changes the things, try to subscribe on `router.events` and console.log all of them. Then you should see all events about the url and what happens with it. Post the log here and we'll find the issue. perhaps there's another condition that redirects back.